# is Command appropriate software pattern for this?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have following task:

I need to send several instructions after each other to the hardware. Next instruction is never sent before either answer to previous instruction comes (valid answer or error) or timeout happens.

Currently all of those instruction has their own listeners with *onReceived(answer)* and *onError(ErrorCode)*, and next instruction is called from onReceived of previous.. As you can imagine this code is not optimal and by adding new instruction to the sequence, class get even more cluttered and it is harder to maintain or debug.

My goal would be to have some kind of simple class that will have list of instructions in correct order and every instruction to have way to process it's own received answer and store it in common place. This simple manager class would just call execute() or next() and correct instruction would be sent, answer would be stored if correct or command repeated certain number of times in case of error.

Command pattern seems to be way to go but I am not sure if I am on the right track and how to react to responses in a correct way.

Comment: This doesn't really help you, but as it happens I'm _right now_ working on extending a little scripting language that I created to abstract all of this away in the same scenario. Because you're right: doing it all in the actual source code is not scalable whatsoever. Instead of a sequence of event handlers, I have a script parser and a script execution engine and — along with tons of automatically-managed internal state — all the sequencing logic is now done for me. I just need to write a text file with the instructions I want to perform. I have conditionals, loops, variables... :D

Comment: my case is even more complicated because I know basic instruction in advance but some of them are parameterized. For example parameter for instruction #5 is known from received answer #3.

Comment: That's what the variables are for ;)